# Using Java.sql result set to instantiate class so I can call my constructor

Tags: java, postgresql, prepared-statement, resultset

Sorry for the confusing title, I didn't know how else to word my problem. So I have an accounts class which has an instance of a Customer class as an argument in the constructor. I am implementing select statements for the Accounts DAO and I am unsure how to use Resultset to get the instance of a customer class so I can  instantiate an account. Is this even possible, or am I approaching it incorrectly? Code below is my account.java file which has setters and getters

```
public class Account {

    private String acctName;
    private Integer acctID;
    private Double acctTotal;
    private Customer owner;

public Account(Customer user, String name, Integer accountID, Double acctTotal) {
    this.acctName = name;
    this.acctID = accountID;
    this.acctTotal = acctTotal;
    this.owner = user;
}
```

Code below is one of the select statements in the Account DAO. How would I get the instance of customer with the Resultset?

```
 public List<Account> selectAllAccount() {

    List<Account> allAccounts = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        //Create a connection to DB and prepare select statement
        Connection myConnect = super.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = myConnect.prepareStatement("SELECT * from Account");

        //Store query result to build list of Accounts
        ResultSet queryResult = ps.executeQuery();

        //while data in query result create Account list
        while(queryResult.next()){

            String AccountName = queryResult.getString("AcctName");
            Integer id = queryResult.getInt("AcctID");
            Double acctTotal = queryResult.getDouble('acctTotal');

            
            ***//this is the call I am having trouble understanding how to implement with Resultset*** 
            Customer cus = queryResult.getObject(); //This is not right

            Account Account = new Account(cus, AccountName, id, acctTotal);
            allAccounts.add(Account);
        }

        return allAccounts;
```

Comment: Update the query to join with the with Customer table?

Comment: You might want to look into an ORM such as Hibernate: https://hibernate.org/orm/what-is-an-orm/